# nodejs express automatic url normalization and redirection

Tags: node.js, express, security

It seems that express default behaviour is to normalize URLs containing up directory (/../)

For the code below, if I request a URL like this

```
http://localhost:8080/foo/../../bar
```

the request gets redirected to

```
http://localhost:8080/bar
```

I couldn't find any detailed documentation on this behavior.

my questions are:

- is it a guaranteed behavior
- in case I am not serving from a file system is there a way to preserve the original URL "path" in case i am using other processing?

by

```
const express = require("express")
const app=express()

app.get("/*", (req,res) => {
  console.log("url:",req.url);
  console.log("path:",req.path);
  res.send('echo for url='+req.url+'; path='+req.path')
}

const port=8080;
app.listen(port,() =>{
  console.log(`listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

Comment: is it a guaranteed behaviour, yes. is there a way to preserve, no, you would need to use `?path=foo/../../bar` and access via `req.query.path`, FYI, if you do `../../../../../` its not going to serve any higher up path then the server root, you cant do `/~` and it go into home directory etc, a browser is not a filesystem explorer, despite what it might look like when you use file://

Comment: How do you know it is guaranteed behavior ? is there a documentation reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request is not redirected, but rather the client rebuilds the URL *before* making the request

```
>curl -v http://localhost:8080/foo/../../bar
* Rebuilt URL to: http://localhost:8080/bar
```

Therefore the server never sees the "original URL path".

This URL rebuilding is part of the [resolution process](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-5.2). See also https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-basic-url-parser.

A malicious client (e.g., a telnet client) could, however, send an HTTP request with "unresolved" URL. The following middleware demonstrates how to rebuild the URL on the server:

```js
function(req, res) {
  res.json({path: req.path,
            rebuilt_path: new URL("s://" + req.path).pathname});
}
```

The malicious request

```
GET /foo/../../bar HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
```

then returns

```json
{"path": "/foo/../../bar", "rebuilt_path": "/bar"}
```

(Things get more complicated if [`req.baseUrl`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.baseUrl) is also involved.)

Comment: what about a malicious or deficient client which doesn't rebuild correctly ? Will the server do a rebuild too?

Comment: See my edited answer.